# Send Form data to server and store it in the server using Java script

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a form page and I would like to submit the form details to my server, and store the details within the server.

I need a script to send the client's request to the server and I thought of using JavaScript.

I came across XMLHttpRequest while searching.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is a client-side scripting language, it can not store anything on your server as you will need a server-side scripting language.

The first part of drawing a form and asking the user for the data is easy and can be done in HTML, and some jQuery if you would like it nice looking. The server-side will require a PHP/ASP script that will store or send the submitted data.

Example:

HTML (form.html):

```
<form method="POST" action="store.php">
Enter Your Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" />
</form>
```

PHP (store.php):

```
<?php
 foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
 {
    $contents .= "$name = $value" . "\n";
 }

 // save locally in cache folder
 $fd = fopen("cache/filename.txt", "w");
 fwrite($fd, $contents);
 fclose($fd);

 // mail me the submitted data
 @mail("me@there.com", "some subject", $contents);

 // die in piece
 die();
?>
```

Comment: I have this form page with a submit button ,the onclick parameter points towards a function which sends form details to the server, " onclick=172.16.151.31/receive.php " , the receive.php , would accept the parameters and store it in a text file .

Comment: Yes, your report.php should receive the passed form field information by parsing the $_POST server variable, then saving or sending it as illustrated above. The easiest way to check if the receive.pgp is getting the data is to enter a line like print_r($_POST);

Comment: the function which submits the form would be only having this entry right?                                                      function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}

Comment: Depends, you can do the same single thing with Javascript in a 100 different ways.. but generally speaking, the code you showed is correct, assuming your form *name* is myform.. and you have the correct onclick inserted in place for the active button. Want my advise, check jQuery Ajax, much faster and much more accurate results ;)