# 403 error in lighttpd server in my debian linux server while trying to store form data in a text file. How do I solve this

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I had created a html form and was trying to store it in a text file using PHP but I kept getting a 403 error. It's most probably because it does not have write permission . How do I give the script the permission to write in the directory? (I'm using the Raspbian Wheezy distro)

```
    <form method="POST" action="store.php">
    Enter Your Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" />
    </form>
```

and for the server

```
    <?php
    foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
   {
        $contents .= "$name = $value" . "\n";
    }

    // save locally in cache folder
    $fd = fopen("cache/filename.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fd, $contents);
    fclose($fd);




    die();
    ?>
```

Comment: inablity to write a file in php will NOT throw a 403 error at the http level. 403's generally get thrown when you're trying to browse a directory on which browsing's been disabled.

Comment: Could it be because the directory of the text file was beyond the boundaries of browsing. Would it work if I stored the text file in the same folder as the web pages ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218814/send-form-data-to-server-and-store-it-in-the-server-using-javascript
i used this code

Comment: shouldn't matter where the text file is. PHP code can access any files anywhere on the server, if the webserver's account has access to it. What matters is how you're writing the file. Show some actual code.

Comment: I have added it with the question

Comment: it looks like your file isn't in the apache group `ls -l <yourfile>`

Answer (score 0):

The `403` you're receiving is probably unrelated to the actual PHP code itself. As a general rule, an error in PHP will generate `5xx` status codes, not `4xx`.

Have you made sure that the webserver account has execute permissions on your PHP file?

Comment: No, how do I check if it has permissions in a debian system